# JavaScript array element to string

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

i have a simple array and i want to generate string which include all the elements of the array, for example:

The array is set as follow:

```
array[0] = uri0
array[1] = uri1
array[2] = uri2
```

And the output string must be

```
teststring = uri0,uri1,uri2
```

I've tried to make this following way (using for loop):

```
var teststring = "";
teststring = teststring+array[y]
```

but in the firebug console i see an error message:

```
"teststring is not defined"
```

I don't know, what I'm doing wrong. Can someone give me a hint?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You must use the join function on the array:

```
var teststring = array.join(",");
```

Answer (score 11):

```
array.join();
```

That is the correct answer.  If no value is supplied to the join method a comma is the default element separator.  Use the following if you don't want any separator at all:

```
array.join("");
```

Comment: Like the default explanation.  Shows more in depth knowledge

Answer (score 7):

```
array.join(",")
```

Answer (score 0):

For ***comma*** based join, you could use ***toString()*** method of ***Object.prototype*** (***Array object*** internally inherit it automatically). For other **separator** based join use **join** method of the Array object.

```js
var array = [];
array[0] = 'uri0';
array[1] = 'uri1';
array[2] = 'uri2';

console.log(array.toString()); // uri0,uri1,uri2

console.log(array.join(" £ ")); // uri0 £ uri1 £ uri2
```

Other possible option is ***implicit type coercion***:

```js
// String conversion by implicit coercion
// using '+ operator' and empty string operand ('' , [])
console.log(array + ''); // uri0,uri1,uri2
console.log(array + []); // uri0,uri1,uri2
```