# splitting a string with sub-groups

Tags: javascript

I have the following javascript string varaible:

```
var a = "1870|A00,1871|A01";
```

I want to separate the above string into the below strings:

```
var a1 = 1870,1871
var a2 = A00,A01
```

Any hints on this?

Comment: This is simply a case of [splitting a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/96428/how-do-i-split-this-string-with-javascript) twice and then [joining some of the arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353579/javascript-array-element-to-string). Not sure if it counts as a duplicate, but it's awfully close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var a = "1870|A00,1871|A01";

var b = a.split(',');     // split on the commas
var a1 = [], a2 = [];     // temporary arrays

// foreach of the substrings
for (var i = 0; i < b.length; ++i) {
    var c = b[i].split('|');  // split on the pipe char
    a1.push(c[0]);            // and store the
    a2.push(c[1]);            // two elements
}

a1 = a1.join(',');        // and reconstruct the
a2 = a2.join(',');        // two strings
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var a = "1870|A00,1871|A01";
var a1 = a.match(/\d+(?=\|)/g);
var a2 = a.match(/\w\d+(?=,|$)/g);

// a1
// 1870,1871
// a2
// A00,A01
```

Comment: Mark:Thanks,I want exactly like this way.

Answer (score 2):

To split a string the Javascript [split method](http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascript-string-split.php) can be used.  Split accepts as a parameter the delimiter you want to split on, in your case the comma and the pipe.  It returns an array of objects found before and after the delimiter (which ends up being an array sized one larger than the number of times the delimiter appears).

To add an object to an array on the fly for building up your a1 and a2, use [push](http://ilovethecode.com/Javascript/Javascript-Tutorials-How_To-Easy/Javascript_Push_-_Use_Push_on_an_Array_in_Javascript.shtml).  Push adds an object to the end of an array.

To get a string from your two arrays with commas separating each, use [join](http://ilovethecode.com/Javascript/Javascript-Tutorials-How_To-Easy/Javascript_Join_-_Use_Join_to_Make_an_Array_into_a_String_in_Javascript.shtml).  Join takes an array and returns a string with whatever your argument is separating each entry.

```
var a1 = [];
var a2 = [];
var firstGrouping = a.split(",");
var firstGroupingLength = firstGrouping.length;
for(var i = 0; i < firstGroupingLength; i++) {
    var secondGrouping = firstGrouping[i].split("|");
    a1.push(secondGrouping[0]);
    a2.push(secondGrouping[1]);
}
var a1String = a1.join(',');
var a2String = a2.join(',');
```

To generalize the code above to allow for more items grouped around the pipe (such as an input string `var a = "1870|Z26|A00,1871|Z25|A01"`), instead of a1 and a2 consider an array of arrays that is constructed dynamically.

Comment: Don't forget to `join` `a1` and `a2`.

Answer (score 0):

Try Google next time, use the .split() - http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp method. To split your string into an array like so.

```
    var a="1870|A00,1871|A01";
    var parts = a.split(",");
```

Comment: Proper documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = "1870|A00,1871|A01"

var splita = a.split(",");

splita[0] = splita[0].split("|");
splita[1] = splita[1].split("|");

var a1 = [splita[0][0], splita[1][0]];
var a2 = [splita[0][1], splita[1][1]];
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done fairly easily using a regular expression replace.

```
var a1 = a.replace(/\|A[0-9]+/,"");
var a2 = a.replace(/[0-9]+\|/,"");
```

I have not tried the code but it should work.