# Node js Mysql query IN clasue and array of strings

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am trying to pass array of cities to the IN clause but seems inverted commas are removed while preparing query

Here is the code

```
let city = ["Moscow", "Paris"];
let sql = 'SELECT* FROM cities WHERE city IN ('+city+')';
console.log(sql);
```

and in the console I am getting this

```
SELECT* FROM cities WHERE city IN (Moscow, Paris);
```

and thus getting exception while executing query!

Any help?

Comment: Try with string interpolation.

Comment: You shouldn't concatenate an array with a string using `+`. Try with `join` on the array instead to build your string first

Comment: can you tell which package are you using for connecting to mysql?

Comment: Use ORM or Query Builder for querying.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript array element to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353579/javascript-array-element-to-string)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this, it will work

```
var sql = "SELECT uid FROM cities where city IN ('" + gender.join("','") + "')";
```

Result :-

```
SELECT uid FROM cities where city IN ('Male','Female')
```

Answer (score 4):

Using a Query Builder is a preferable method but a possible solution if you have a long array:

```
let stringifiedValues = JSON.stringify(city).replace(/\[|\]/g,'');
let sql = `SELECT * FROM cities WHERE city IN (${stringifiedValues})`;
```

Comment: This is an interesting solution for this task! If you don't like RegExp, you can use `JSON.stringify(city).slice(1, -1)`

Answer (score 1):

1. Use the [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function to transform all items in your array. You want to add *quotes* to the items like this `Moscow` => `'Moscow'`
2. Use the [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to gather the transformed items into a *string*. The delimiter can be specified as an argument like this `array.join(', ')`
3. Use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) (string interpolation) to inject your string in your *query*. Like this `${str}`

```js
const city = ["Moscow", "Paris"];
const injectedString = city.map(c => `'${c}'`).join(', ');

let sql = `SELECT * FROM cities WHERE city IN (${injectedString})`;
console.log(sql);
```